# Android battery performance NmeaListner vs LocationListner

Tags: android, gps, nmea

I want to use NmeaListner to get raw gps data in my android app.
Due to various reasons I cannot use the standard location listner for a particular use case.

Does this consume same amount of battery as using standard location listner ? Will it consume less ? More?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should consume the same amount of battery running NMEA vs locations.

The battery usage comes from running the GPS receiver in the first place, turning on the receiver radio, and processing fixes.  NMEA is probably generated by your gps receiver whenever you have it turned on, all the nmea listener does is direct that stream into a place you can use it in your app.